# is to be posible in mysql repeat the same result

Tags: mysql

I have a select with 1 result only

ex:
SELECT + FROM table1

I need try it with a lot of results, is to be possibe add any word in this select to repeat this a lot of times with the same result.

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you are talking about. Can you clarify?

Comment: if your query only returns one result, why would you want to modify the query to return the same (duplicate) records in a repeating manner?  Usually it's bad to return duplicate records, and people have spent a lot of time writing queries to find / delete duplicates.

Comment: Is only for test, I have 1 row entered in database, but I can try the page for 100 times.

Comment: If mysql had proper sequence support this would be trivial. As it stands as far as I can see this is somewhat tricky and requires a kludge to generate a sequence that can be paired with your results appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more rows to `table1` for example. Or you can use a bunch of unions:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM table1
```

etc.

Comment: Yes it is worksm but doesn't exist other more automatic method?

Answer (score 1):

You could add some cross joins in. Each additional cross join will multiply the number of results by the size of the cross joined table.

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c1, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c2, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c3, 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing the then you should add duplicate data to the database instead of modifying your query. Run this query 10 to 12 times:

INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT * FROM TABLE1;

Answer (score -1):

Eh, that's not how SQL works. It'll return all rows that match your query parameters.

If you give us an actually query I could be more specific about what's happening.