# MySQL, how to repeat same line x times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that outputs address order data:

```
SELECT ordernumber
  , article_description
  , article_size_description
  , concat(NumberPerBox,' pieces') as contents
  , NumberOrdered
FROM customerorder
WHERE customerorder.id = 1;
```

I would like the above line to be outputted `NumberOrders` (e.g. 50,000) divided by `NumberPerBox` e.g. 2,000 = 25 times.

Is there a SQL query that can do this, I'm not against using temporary tables to join against if that's what it takes.

I checked out the previous questions, however the nearest one:
[is to be posible in mysql repeat the same result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994814/is-to-be-posible-in-mysql-repeat-the-same-result)
Only gave answers that give a fixed number of rows, and I need it to be dynamic depending on the value of (`NumberOrdered div NumberPerBox`).

The result I want is:

```
Boxnr   Ordernr        as_description   contents   NumberOrdered
------+--------------+----------------+-----------+---------------
  1   | CORDO1245    | Carrying bags  | 2,000 pcs | 50,000
  2   | CORDO1245    | Carrying bags  | 2,000 pcs | 50,000
....
  25  | CORDO1245    | Carrying bags  | 2,000 pcs | 50,000
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired result in more detail?  An example might help

Comment: Feels a bit dirty, but if you always have a *reasonably small* number of rows.. you could have a counter table (single column, numbers 1 to largest anticipated result size), join the results of your query with the counter table and restrict the number of rows returned (this seems to be SQL specific, in oracle you could use rownum, not sure what MYSQL's equivalent is).

Comment: I’m very curious why it is necessary to do this in SQL rather than at the application layer, if you’re able to briefly explain?

Comment: It needs to connect to a QReport, if I put it in a Query there's no extra code required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me say that I am more familiar with SQL Server so my answer has a bit of a bias.
Second, I did not test my code sample and it should probably be used as a reference point to start from.

It would appear to me that this situation is a prime candidate for a numbers table.  Simply put, it is a table (usually called "Numbers") that is nothing more than a single PK column of integers from 1 to n.  Once you've used a Numbers table and aware of how it's used, you'll start finding many uses for it - such as querying for time intervals, string splitting, etc.

That said, here is my untested response to your question:

```
SELECT
   IV.number as Boxnr
  ,ordernumber  
  ,article_description
  ,article_size_description
  ,concat(NumberPerBox,' pieces') as contents
  ,NumberOrdered
FROM
  customerorder
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
       Numbers.number
      ,customerorder.ordernumber
      ,customerorder.NumberPerBox
    FROM
      Numbers
      INNER JOIN customerorder
        ON Numbers.number BETWEEN 1 AND customerorder.NumberOrdered / customerorder.NumberPerBox
    WHERE
      customerorder.id = 1
    ) AS IV
    ON customerorder.ordernumber = IV.ordernumber
```

As I said, most of my experience is in SQL Server.  I reference http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/2547/ (registration required).  However, there appears to be quite a few resources available when I search for "SQL numbers table".

Comment: the derived table isn't necessary -- a top-level `customerorder INNER JOIN Numbers` can do the trick.

Comment: I wondered about that, but couldn't test my suggestion.  Thanks!